# Spark 2.0 set jars

Tags: scala, apache-spark, jar, apache-spark-2.0

I am upgrading to spark 2.0 from 1.6 in a play-scala application and am not quite sure how to set the jar files I want. Previously a SparkConf would be defined and one of the methods I could call was setJars, which allowed me to specify all of the jar files I wanted. Now I am using SparkSession builder to construct my spark conf and spark context and I do not see any similar methods for specifying the jar files? How can I do this?

Here is how I previously created my sparkconf:

```
val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setMaster(sparkMaster).setAppName(sparkAppName).
  set("spark.yarn.jar", "hdfs:///user/hadoop/spark-assembly-1.6.1-hadoop2.7.2.jar").
  set("spark.eventLog.dir", "hdfs:///var/log/spark/apps").
  set("spark.eventLog.enabled", "true").
  set("spark.executorEnv.JAVA_HOME", "/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0-openjdk").
  setJars(Seq(
    "ALL JAR FILES LISTED HERE"
  ))
```

What can I do using sparksession builder to accomplish the same thing as "setJars"?

Answer (score 11):

You can use `.config(key, value)` method to set `spark.jars`:

```
SparkSession.builder
 .appName(sparkAppName)
 .master(sparkMaster)
 .config("spark.jars", commaSeparatedListOfJars)
 .config(/* other stuff */)
 .getOrCreate()
```

Comment: Glad to hear - please accept and/or upvote the answer to signify this for future readers.

Comment: when I use this I can't seem to give the path to the jar. I am not able to use maven in my case